# 外部シンボルが未解決というエラーが出てしまう

Tags: c++, visual-studio

みなさんありがとうございました！
こちらのサイトの内容はいくらやっても理解できなかったので
新しいサイトを参考に制作します！ありがとうございました！

https://bituse.info/game/shot/9
こちらのサイトを参考にシュミレーションゲームを制作しようとしています

それで、敵を追加する項目でg_count;という拡張子が見当たらないとエラーが出てしまったでサイトをよく見ると

> まず、最初に説明しておかなければならないのは、変数g_countです。
> これはゲームが開始してから何ループしたのかを表す変数です。
> これはmain.cppでグローバル変数として定義し、define.hでextern宣言して共有できるようにしています。

と説明されていたので
main.cpp に　int g_count;　と追加し
define.h に　extern int g_count;　と追加したところ見たことないエラーが出てしまい色々試したのですが解決できません。
どなたか分かる方助けてほしいです。

**追記**
お返事のほうありがとうございます。
またシステムの根幹から作り直そうかなと考えています。
とりあえず今の敵が実装できないエラーを解決したいのでそこまでは終わらせようと思います。
ソリューションをアップしたほうがいいとのことで
https://dotup.org/uploda/dotup.org2294152.zip.html
こちらに上げさせていただきました。

よろしくお願いします。

---

**エラーメッセージ**

```
1>------ ビルド開始: プロジェクト: gamegame, 構成: Release Win32 ------
1>back.cpp
1>control.cpp
1>enemy.cpp
1>main.cpp
1>pch.cpp
1>player.cpp
1>control.obj : error LNK2001: 外部シンボル "int g_count" (?g_count@@3HA) は未解決です
1>C:\Users\rikua\source\repos\gamegame\Release\gamegame.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 1 件の未解決の外部参照
1>プロジェクト "gamegame.vcxproj" のビルドが終了しました -- 失敗。
========== ビルド: 0 正常終了、1 失敗、0 更新不要、0 スキップ ==========
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include "pch.h"
#include "control.h"



//キー取得用配列
char key[256];

int g_count;

// プログラムは WinMain から始まります
int WINAPI WinMain( HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow )
{
    ChangeWindowMode(TRUE);

    if( DxLib_Init() == -1 )        // ＤＸライブラリ初期化処理
    {
        return -1 ;         // エラーが起きたら直ちに終了
    }


    CONTROL *control = new CONTROL;

    

    while(ScreenFlip()==0 && ProcessMessage()==0 && ClearDrawScreen()==0 && GetHitKeyStateAll(key)==0){
        
        control->All();
        
    }


    DxLib_End() ;               // ＤＸライブラリ使用の終了処理

    return 0 ;              // ソフトの終了 
}
```

**define.h**

```
#include <windows.h>

//プレイヤーの歩くスピード
#define PLAYER_SPEED 5

#define MARGIN 10

//メッセージボックス
#define MSG(m) {\
    MessageBox(NULL,m,"メッセージ",MB_OK);}

//extern宣言してkey配列にどこからでもアクセスできるようにする
extern char key[256];
extern int g_count;
    


#pragma once

#define PSHOT_NUM 20
#define PSHOT_SPEED 14
struct SHOT {
    bool flag;//弾が発射中かどうか
    double x;//x座標
    double y;//y座標
    int gh;//グラフィックハンドル
    int width, height;//画像の幅と高さ
};
```

**enemy.cpp**

```
#include "pch.h"
#include "enemy.h"

ENEMY::ENEMY()
{
    LoadDivGraph("enemy.png", 3, 1, 3, 27, 25, gh);

    width = 27;
    height = 25;

    x = 50;
    y = -50;

    in_time = 180;

    stop_time = 300;

    out_time = 420;

    count = 0;

    endflag = false;

}


void ENEMY::Move()
{
    //出てきてから止まる時間までの間なら下に移動
    if (in_time < g_count && g_count < stop_time) {
        y += 2;
        //帰還時間を過ぎたら戻る。
    }
    else if (g_count > out_time) {
        y -= 2;
        if (y < -40) {
            endflag = true;
        }
    }
}

void ENEMY::Draw()
{
    int temp;

    if (!endflag) {

        temp = count % 40 / 10;
        if (temp == 3)
            temp = 1;

        DrawGraph(x, y, gh[temp], TRUE);
    }
}


bool ENEMY::All()
{
    Move();

    Draw();

    ++count;

    return endflag;
}
```

**enemy.h**

```
#include "pch.h"
class ENEMY {
private:
    double x, y;
    int gh[3];

    int width, height;

    int in_time, stop_time, out_time;

    int count;

    bool endflag;

public:
    bool All();
    void Move();
    void Draw();
    ENEMY();
};
```

**control.cpp**

```
#include "pch.h"
#include "control.h"


CONTROL::CONTROL()
{
    //プレイヤークラスの生成
    player = new PLAYER;

    

    back = new BACK;

}

CONTROL::~CONTROL()
{
    //プレイヤークラスの解放
    delete player;


    
}

void CONTROL::All()
{

    //描画領域を指定
    SetDrawArea(MARGIN, MARGIN, MARGIN + 380, MARGIN + 460);

    back->All();



    player->All();


    if (enemy != NULL) {
        if (enemy->All()) {
            delete enemy;
            enemy = NULL;
        }
    }

    ++g_count;
}
```

Comment: 質問に書かれた`main.cpp`のソースには`int g_count;`が追加されていないようですが。

Comment: see also; https://dixq.net/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&p=155255&sid=297e1d3cf0ab4a79c0963e011abee250#p155255 ここんちだと `int g_count;` は追加されている様子

Comment: 参照先サイトの記事では、説明が進むごとにソースをドンドン書き変えて機能追加している(かつ未完成の)ようですので、記事を紹介されても、ソースの一部だけ質問に提示されても検証が難しいですね。何処かに現在のソリューション全体をアップロードして、其処へのリンクを貼ってもらった方が良さそうです。あとこちらマルチポスト先 [外部シンボルが未解決というエラーが出てしまう](https://teratail.com/questions/299864) の「その記事を参考にするのは考え直した方が良い」の助言に解決マークを付けたようですので、方針転換でしょうか？

Comment: とりあえず、[間違えてアカウントを 2 件作成してしまいました。どうしたらマージできますか？](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/merging-accounts)に従ってアカウントを統合する必要があるかもしれません。

Comment: なぜかアカウントが二つになってしまったで統合しようと奮闘しています。
皆さんありがとうございます！

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 1>control.obj : error LNK2001: 外部シンボル "int g_count" (?g_count@@3HA) は未解決です

要は、g_count を宣言して使用しているにも関わらず、どこでも定義してないってことです。
まずエラーメッセージを調べ、内容を理解してください。
エラーコードをGoogle検索すればすぐに情報は出てくる筈です。

[Linker Tools Error LNK2001](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/cpp/error-messages/tool-errors/linker-tools-error-lnk2001?view=msvc-160)

英語でよく判らん、という場合はChromeの翻訳機能等や翻訳サイトを使ってください。そこそこ読める日本語になります。翻訳して説明を読んで、それでも判らんという場合は、単純に開発言語に対する理解不足です。もっと勉強してください。せめて、宣言と定義くらいは理解しましょう。
[宣言 (declaration) と定義 (definition) の違い](https://so-zou.jp/software/tech/programming/cpp/grammar/data-type/declaration/definition.htm)

エラーには問題解決のための情報が入っているので、まず最低限エラーの文章をきちんと読むのと、Web検索をするくらいはやりましょう。

Answer (score 1):

C++17には[インライン変数](https://cpprefjp.github.io/lang/cpp17/inline_variables.html)という機能があります。ヘッダーファイルに

```
inline int g_count = 0;
```

と（宣言ではなく）定義を書くことができます。

Visual C++は互換のためデフォルトでC++14までしか有効化されていないため、コンパイルオプション[`/std:c++17`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/std-specify-language-standard-version?view=msvc-160)の指定が必要です。

Answer (score 0):

アップロードされていた`.zip`の中の`main.cpp`には`int g_count;`が追加されていませんでした。

主に`main.cpp`に`int g_count;`を追加してビルドしたら正常に終了し、デバッグ実行でそれなりに動いているようです。(カーソルキーでキャラを動かすことが出来ています)

以下のような状況が考えられます。

- ビルド対象では無い、例えば参照先サイトからダウンロードしてセーブしておいたフォルダの`main.cpp`を編集している。
- Visual Studio IDE上ではなく、別のエディタ上でファイルを編集していて、しかも編集内容をファイルに反映させていない。

---

アップロードされていた`.zip`内のソースファイルを基に、以下のような手順で確認しました。

1. Visual Studio Community 2019 で新しいプロジェクトの作成で C++,Windows,デスクトップ の Windowsデスクトップウィザードを選択
2. `gamegame`というソリューション＆プロジェクト名で作成
3. `デスクトップアプリケーション(.exe)`で`空のプロジェクト`をチェックし、OKで作成
4. `.zip`ファイルから各`.cpp`, `.h`ファイルをコピーしてプロジェクトに追加
5. メニューの`プロジェクト`の`NuGetパッケージの管理`の`参照`で`DxLib`で検索し、`DxLib.vc140`をインストール
6. `.cpp`, `.h`の画像ファイル名やメッセージ文言の文字列リテラルを`_T()`マクロで囲む

---

7. 上記時点でビルドすると、質問記事のように「外部シンボル "int g_count" (?g_count@@3HA) は未解決です」となる

---

8. `main.cpp`に`int g_count;`が無いので、追加してビルドすると正常に終了し、出来た.exeをデバッグ実行するとウインドウ・背景イメージ・キャラが表示され、キャラをカーソルキーで動かすことが出来る